# Gmail Addon autocomplete doesn't allow more than 30 items in the list

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

```html
var autoComplete = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName('autoComplete')
    .setTitle('Auto Complete')
    .setSuggestions(CardService.newSuggestions()
        .addSuggestions([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40]);
```

This widget limits the no. of options in the dropdown to `30`, I couldn't find any reference to this limit in the documentation.

[image: Gmail Addon Autocomplete]

I was trying to add a field for `Currency` for an add-on I am working on.

Did anyone figure what can be done about this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem adding more than 30 items:

```
var zSuggestions = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34'];
    var widget = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setTitle('some title')
    .setFieldName('some_name')
    .setValue('3')
    .setSuggestions(CardService.newSuggestions()
    .addSuggestions(zSuggestions));
```

and in fact have done upwards of 200. Wonder if there's been a recent change?

Comment: Could be, will check this out